# Create a docker volume for DotNet to read a file

Tags: .net, docker, volumes

To Devs, I am doing a simple console app in Dotnet, creating an image and then a container with a volume that has a file. I would like to read that file from the container and output another file in that volume.  My docker cli for creating the volume is:

```
docker run test:latest -v target:\App
```

When I inspect the container, no volumes are mounted.
I would then like to read a file from that volume and then write it out.
Any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Options on the `docker run` command are split into two kinds. Options for docker are placed *before* the image name and options for the image are placed *after* the image name (technically, the options for the image replace any CMD command that the image may have).

The `-v` is a Docker option, so it should be placed before the image name, like this

```
docker run -v target:\App test:latest
```

You're using a backslash in `\App` which may be incorrect if you're using a Linux image. Then it should be `/App`. Also be aware that the Linux file system is case sensitive, so `/App` is different from `/app`.